# cmd: How to extract part of a string?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

in windows command line script I have string variable for an example:

AB_CD RR CRR LH 8AH_M22   1.1   2050_gra.pdf

which is a file name, where I need to extract to a different variable string (in this case) 2050 (user entered time).

It is always bounded by at least one space (usually three) on the left side, and always by _gra.pdf on the right side.

It is not always 4 digits long, and someone might put a dot or comma to separate hours and minutes. So it might look also like this:

- 20.50
- 20,50
- 20,50
- 850
- 8.50
- 8,50
- 0850
- 08.50
- 08,50

Basically is anything between _gra.pdf and nearest space on the left side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set "x=AB_CD RR CRR LH 8AH_M22 1.1 2050_gra.pdf"

REM get last element:
for %%i in ("%x: =" "%") do set last=%%i
rem split it by `_`:
for /f "Tokens=1 delims=_" %%i in (%last%) do set utim=%%~i
echo %utim%
```

edit: to meet *"extract anything between _M and next space":*

```
set "x=AB_CD RR CRR LH 8AH_M  22 1.1  2050_gra.pdf"
REM delete anything until (including) "_M":
for %%i in ("%x:*_M=%") do set "y=%%i"
REM get string until next space:
for /f "Tokens=1" %%i in (%y%) do set "utim=%%~i"
echo %utim%
```

Comment: Great. It helped me a lot! Any idea now (to improove tings) how to Extract anything after M, up until next space please? It will be enough to extract 22 in this case.

Those for loops does not say anything to me :/

Comment: a bit more Information would be helpful. Is ìt the only `M` or may there be more of them? Would `_M` be reliable? Or is there the same Count of Elements (separated by spaces)? Or the same Count separated by underscore?

Comment: _M will be reliable. So if we extract anything between _M and next space on right, that will be great. But, there might be _M1 and also _M22 (max 2 digits).

Comment: See my edit. See also `for /?`. `FOR` is one of the most powerful commands in Batch. If you want to use Batch, you really should try to understand it (once you got the idea, it's not _that_ difficult)

Comment: How to get an item at certain count from the end ? Continuously deleting the last with `%v:!v1!=%` isn't reliable .

Comment: @irvnriir: get all tokens and take the `x-n`th. [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309029/split-string-with-variable-length-in-windows-batch). Please ask a new question with your code if you have problems with it.

Comment: @Stephan , All items should be counted, then you `-` the needed range from the end, and use the result to get the item X) sorry for my stupidity

Comment: Exacly. Alternatively, you can count the tokens with a first (plain `for`) loop, do the math, and in a second loop get the desired token with a `for /f` loop.