# Split string with variable length in Windows Batch

Tags: arrays, string, batch-file

I'm actually working on a codifier/decodifier. Now I have to separate numeric groups from others. The length of the numeric groups is unknown but I know they are divided by " " (a space char). I don't know how to proceed, but I can explain my will with a pseudo-code:

```
for x-times (maybe the maximum, like 128) (
group[index] = the first part of the string until " "
string = string minus the first part until " "
)
```

Basically, I want to extract the groups in a single array. Is this possible?
I tried a lot of methods with defined tokens, but my system is completely different.

Comment: Look on this Stack Overflow with search term [\[batch-file\] split string](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+split+string). As you can see this was not asked the first time. For a string with spaces as separator you just need command __FOR__. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` for help on this command.

Comment: Use PowerShell rather than trying to do this in shell script (batch). PowerShell has native string support with substring, built-in support for arrays and structured-language loop statements.

Comment: Sorry but 1) my system is different 2) the possible solution you posted isn't working 3) i'm using batch not powershell.

Comment: There is no need to struggle with shell script (batch) now that we have PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mofi already noted, a simple `for` will do the trick. Add a counter to build up a variable for every "word" (array). Whether they are real words or numbers doesn't matter, but some special chars will generate errors, like `&`, `|` or just being ignored, like `%`, `!`).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
set "string=some substrings with variable lengths separated by space"
for %%a in (%string%) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set substring[!count!]=%%a
)
set substring[
```

Comment: Thank you very much Stephan